# Position a hard-coded menu item

Tags: customization, menus, navigation, links

I used a piece of code I found here in wordpress.stackexchange to add a custom link to my menu/nav. I adapted to my needs and it works great. The problem is it adds the link in the first position in my navigation list but I want it at the end after the other links.

Does anyone know how to make that happen?

```
function new_nav_menu_items($items, $args) {


 if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ){
    $homelink = '<li><a  class="sites-button" data-toggle="animatedModal10">cool</a></li>';
    $items = $homelink . $items;
}
return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items', 1, 2  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
$items = $homelink . $items;
```

to

```
$items = $items . $homelink;
```